# EBS Read Speeds

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

Looking at the C4 specifications at http://www.ec2instances.info/ I see that it has an EBS Optimized bandwidth.

My question is, is this bandwidth on a per EBS volume or for all EBS volumes bandwidth?

Also, is this still going to be bound by the network interface?  If i have other stuff using the bandwidth, will it will eat into my EBS Optimized bandwidth?  Or is some special thing connected to the hard drive interface that doesn't interfere with network performance?

Also, if someone with the rep can make the tag `elastic-block-store` and `ebs` that would be appreciated.

Comment: The established tag is [tag:amazon-ebs]. Added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an EC2 instance is "EBS Optimized", the instance has a dedicated network channel to Amazon EBS. The available bandwidth to Amazon EBS is based on the EC2 instance type.

This means that:

- Non-EBS-related network activity should not affect the network connection to the EBS volumes.
- The bandwidth is across all Amazon EBS volumes attached to the EC2 instance, it is not per EBS volume.

Source: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSOptimized.html